# how to get 'n' tweets from twitter of any user

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, pycharm, python-2.x

I m new in python. help me out.
THE PROBLEM:
i got all tweets of respective user. 
I want n [suppose(n=20)] no of latest tweet of respective user.how to fetch n no of tweets ??
below is my code:

```
def get_all_tweets(screen_name):


    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    alltweets = []
    # make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name,count=200)

    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    print len(alltweets)

    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200, max_id=oldest)

        # save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)


        # update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))



    f = open('testfile.txt', 'w+')
    for tweet in alltweets:
        f.write(str(tweet.text))
        f.write('\n')
        f.close()
    tweets = (tweet.text)
    return tweets
    pass
# to encode the data
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_all_tweets("xyz")
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried editing this line to only get 20?

Change:

```
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200)
```

To:

```
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=20)
```

Comment: it shows same output as this:                                                         new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=200)

Comment: Have you counted how many tweets this is actually returning? It might be capped at 20. Even when you have count set to 200, this doesnt mean it will actually return 200. The API could be capped at 20

Comment: if i set count = 200 it shows:                                                                           "getting tweets before 556815543647215616
...399 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 364321098265272319
...599 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 344033624594735103
...759 tweets downloaded so far
getting tweets before 224551285863624703
...759 tweets downloaded so far"         like this. if count=20 then it shows only difference of 20 to getting tweets

Comment: So does this not answer your question? - if it does you can mark the reply as the answer by clicking the tick

Answer (score 0):

If 'testfile.txt' contains tweets from newest to oldest:

```
n = whatever value you want
tweetArr = []
f = open("test file.txt:, "r")
count = 1
for line in f:

    if count <= n:
        tweetArr.append(line)

    count += 1
```

tweetArr contains the n most recent tweets